# Disallow CI pipelines of one GitLab project to run concurrently?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab

On an internal GitLab server there is one project with a CI script not tolerating concurrent execution of multiple pipelines (external side effects in Kubernetes). So if two commits are pushed in succession with less time in between than the first pipeline needs to finish, the two pipelines will run concurrently, which causes both to fail.

Globally setting `concurrent = 1` for the CI runner (one K8s runner used across multiple repos) is not practicable in that case, because pipelines of other projects using that runner should be allowed to run simultaneously.

Is it possible to disallow CI concurrency only for one project? Canceling the older pipeline or queuing up the newer one would both be OK.

Comment: How about setting the `limit = 1` in the runner? As mentioned in https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/18224

Comment: @TarunLalwani Thanks. However it's one Kubernetes runner used across multiple repositories. So such a setting would not only affect the repo in question.

Comment: @TarunLalwani: I guess we can configure a separate runner for this one repo and set `limit = 1` for it. So your suggestion is very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `limit =1` as discussed in below link

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/18224

```
concurrent = 3 // Attribute that limits a number of projects
check_interval = 0
[[runners]]
  limit = 1 // Attribute that limits quantity job by runners
  name = "test-ci"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/ci"
  token = "38274bf1655a0f48d72b15815a83d4e6a85689"
  executor = "shell"
  [runners.cache]

[[runners]]
  limit = 1
  name = "teste2"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/ci"
  token = "38274bf1655a0f48d72b15815a83d4e6a85689"
  executor = "shell"
  [runners.cache]
```

Instead of using a shared runner, use a project specific runner in your case, so other projects are not impacted

Comment: I tried to do that, but when the specific runner is busy, jobs for that project are just picked up by the shared runner, and then they end up running in parallel anyway.

Comment: As stated by the docs, the `limit` is on concurrent jobs, not pipelines. Runner can still start pipeline 2 job 1 before finishing pipeline 1.
https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html

Comment: I am facing same issue but this solution does not seem working.

Answer (score 3):

You can now use a **[resource group](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/resource_groups/)** to prevent jobs from being run concurrently. See the introduction docs from 2020 [here](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2020/01/21/introducing-resource-groups/).

To ensure that a job only runs once at any given time (i.e. to prevent concurrent runs), you can add the `resource_group` key to your job with some unique name:

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script: echo "Your deployment script"
  resource_group: production
```

Furthermore, you can set the ["process mode"](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/resource_groups/#process-modes) of the resource group to specify the **order** in which jobs should be run. The `oldest_first` is the more obvious one where the jobs will be run in the order in which they've been created.

You'll need to use the API to update the process mode of the resource group after first creating it. For example:

```
curl --location --request PUT 'https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/:project_id/resource_groups/production' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <your token>' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'process_mode=oldest_first'
```