# Gitlab: Is there a way to limit the concurrency jobs in Gitlab by number?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, continuous-delivery

I have a `Gitlab Runner` running on Kubernetes. I see there are options to limit concurrent jobs from the runner level, but it would be preferable if we could do this in `.gitlab-ci.yml` level or from project level, but we can't we find the settings for it.

I saw this [Disallow CI pipelines of one GitLab project to run concurrently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49597850/disallow-ci-pipelines-of-one-gitlab-project-to-run-concurrently) but I am also not sure how to do this on runner deployed on Kubernetes.

If I do this, it won't stop the runner from creating pods still which defeats the purpose of limiting concurrent jobs and control how much resources to be allocated.

I've also looked up `resource_group` but it limits the jobs to `1`, but we want to limit the jobs to `2` or `3` to run concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there now is a way officially supported with [GitLab 14.10](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/04/22/gitlab-14-10-released/#cicd-limits-set-at-the-instance-level) (April 2022):

> ### CI/CD Limits set at the Instance Level
>
> To contain resource usage in support of instance stability, GitLab administrators of instances with high CI/CD usage might want to add limits for specific CI/CD events.
>
> This could be to set:
>
> - the maximum number of jobs in a single pipeline,
> - the maximum number of concurrent jobs in active pipelines, or
> - the maximum number of scheduled pipelines per project.
> - ...
>
> GitLab instance administrators can now set these limits (and others) directly in the instance’s Admin Area panel.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/settings/continuous_integration.html#set-cicd-limits) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/357324).